# linux sort command with delimiter in data

Tags: linux, sorting, csv

I need to sort a big csv file .So,using

> sort

command will be quite good.

But, I am facing an issue that delimiter ',' is also present in the data . 
So, sorting on fields with ',' works unexpectedly .

The file contains data like

```
Ahmedabad ,"7,Olive residency ", 380058
Gandhinagar,"85,Kabir villa",38048
Surat ,Binory Bunglows,589635
```

And I am using sort command like

```
 sort --field-separator=',' -s -k 3,3  bigfile.csv
```

Which does not give desired output.

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: You should probably just bite the bullet and use a CSV parser.

Comment: or reexport the data with a field delilmiter that is not in your data. The <tab> character is often very useful, as it is difficult (but not impossible) for <tab> to be inserted into an on-line data entry form. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
sort -k3 -t',' -nr bigfile.csv
```

Comment: While this does answer the question, it is very very skimpy. You should add at least a sentence of discussion and maybe a link to the sort(1) documentation.

Comment: Also, I recommend indenting your answer four spaces to display it as code.